Pika function is not beign called inside Celery delayed task
I'm trying to run a rabbitmq message from inside a celery task. I'm trying to notify another service that the task finished. The weird thing is that if I deactivate .delay() it works perfectly. But, the problem is when I combine celery task delayed with pika BlockingConnection. You will see that I initialiced my send_message function in a different thread
Also, I realized that if I press ctrl+S (because I'm with flask dev sever) it reloads the server and it sends the messages ... interesting.
Notice that Celery is running over redis and I'm using rabbitmq only with pika.
This is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  reports:
    build:
      context: ../reports
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: horario-reports
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - backend
      - redis
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .reports.env
    volumes:
      - ../reports:/app
  backend:
    build:
      context: ../backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: horario-backend
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .backend.env
    volumes:
      - ../backend:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules
  db:
    container_name: my-postgres-container
    image: postgres:16.2
    env_file:
      - .database.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.13-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    container_name: redis
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
      
volumes:
  postgres_data:

My reports service's Dockerfile is:
FROM python:3.11

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf \
    && apt-get install zip -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000


COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"] 


# entrypoint

python wsgi.py & sleep 5
celery -A main.celery worker --loglevel INFO

My requirements.txt are:
; ...

pika==1.3.2
celery==5.4.0
redis==5.0.4

; ...

this is my celery config:
# main.py
app.config.from_mapping(
    CELERY=dict(
        broker_url="redis://redis:6379/0",
        result_backend="redis://redis:6379/0",
        task_ignore_result=True,
    ),
)
celery = celery_init_app(app)


# celery_conf.py

def celery_init_app(app) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery_app = Celery(app.name, task_cls=FlaskTask)
    celery_app.config_from_object(app.config["CELERY"])
    celery_app.set_default()
    app.extensions["celery"] = celery_app
    return celery_app


from celery import shared_task


@shared_task(ignore_result=True)
def add_together(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    result = a + b
    send_message() # THIS IS THE IMPORTANT THING
    return result


this is my pika/rabbitmq configuration:
# rabbitmq_config.py

import pika


def send_message():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host="rabbitmq"),
    )
    channel = connection.channel()

    queue = "notifications"
    channel.queue_declare(queue=queue)

    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange="", routing_key="notifications", body="Prueba de notificacion"
    )
    print(" [x] Sent 'Hello from PYTHON'")

# wsgi.py
import threading
from main import app
from rabbitmq_config import send_message, start_rmq_connection


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=send_message)
    thread_1.daemon = True
    thread_1.start()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)


FINALLY, this is my endpoint
@app.route("/health", methods=["GET"])
def return_health():
    result = add_together.delay(1, 2) # HERE I CALL MY FUNCTION WITH DELAY
    message = {"status": f"Healthy! <3 {result.id}"}
    return jsonify(message)


That's the thing I'm trying to do.... If you know how to notify when the task finished I'll consider doing it. Thanks a lot :D
